# I want to run java applet in HTML, but it allways have bug

Tags: java, html, security, applet, accesscontrolexception

I try from a long time ago to launch Java applets in browser (they are simple games). For a long time it say out-of-date Java version (now have the latest version 8 update 45), even after I install the latest before 2 min. NVM, I hope  I fixed it. Now it say a lot of different errors: runtime exception or `AccessControlExeption` for ex.

I am running this programs in Eclipse and I tried them, so they work. Maybe I have a problem with HTML code.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas-id" ></canvas>
    </body>

    <applet width="600" height="170" code="theLightRoute.class"></script>
    </applet>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML looks good. Got a stacktrace? Got the Java code to look at? Not every thing a normal Java program can do is allowed to be done by an Applet; there are restrictions.

Comment: `AccessControlExeption` means that applet has tried to do something, which your secutiry permissions don't allow, like read/write a file on the local disk, make a connection to a network outside of the one it originated from ... and lots and lots of others...You might like to have a read through [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: why do you have `</script>` in the middle of your `<applet..></applet>` section? Try removing that?

Comment: in this program it says access control deneied. Here are where i use file writing:

 ` public void save(String dir){
   try {
    writer=new FileWriter(dir,false);
    writer.write("#level\r\n"+level);
    writer.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
   }
  } `

Comment: if the problem is that i load the file from computer, how i can load it from network?

Comment: You should be able to load it from the computer, you just have to grant the right permisson to the applet.

Comment: The HTML is utterly invalid.  Check it using a [validation service](https://validator.w3.org/).  But that is not the underlying problem that causes the `AccesControlException` - that is down to security.  Since the applet code is obviously not digitally signed, there is little chance of getting it to run in a modern Java version.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: your HTML code is not valid, remove the `</script>` closing tag inside your `<applet/>` section. Even if some browsers can accept it, I don't think you can expect to have a valid result with an invalid tag definition.

**Second**: the `<applet/>` tag support can vary regarding the browser (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp). You should try with `<object/>` instead (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

**Third**: you cannot expect anymore that any modern web browser will support a java applet, whatever the tag you use. Indeed, most of them have dropped or disabled by default the browser-side support of any java applet for security reasons. For example for Chrome 42, the java support is totally dropped: http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/chrome-42-npapi. For Firefox or safari it should be enabled manually https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-allow-java-trusted-sites).

Actually, **there is no good reason to create some java applet anymore**, it's a totally deprecated and obsolete technology (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154537/do-java-applets-have-any-place-on-the-web-today).

*Try to learn HTML5 for game programming instead :-) Many courses exist and can help you, and many HTML5 game engine are available (http://html5gameengine.com/). And it is cross-platform, mobile included!*